# What Christian denominations (if any) permit gay marriage?

Tags: denomination-survey, homosexuality

Which churches have decided to permit gay marriage at a denominational level?

Comment: This probably isn't a very good question for this site, as the list is constantly changing.  Any answer provided will be inaccurate within a short period of time.  Further, many denominations don't take a stand on the issue, leaving it up to individual congregations to decide whether to permit it or not, making the list even more complex than at first blush.

Comment: Simply put, this is not definitively answerable.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but I'd second @Flimzy's comment.  The list would be changing and this question would be out-of-date in short order. I'd suggest trying Wikipeda.  I know for a fact [they have a list there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blessing_of_same-sex_unions_in_Christian_churches), and it's likely to be kept updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [United Church of Christ](http://www.ucc.org/index.html):

> Churches in the UCC can sanctify same-sex unions.[28] The resolution
>   "In support of equal marriage rights for all", supported by an
>   estimated 80% of the UCC's 2005 general synod delegates, made the
>   United Church of Christ the first major Christian deliberative body in
>   the U.S. to make a statement of support for "equal marriage rights for
>   all people, regardless of gender," and is hitherto the largest
>   Christian denominational entity in the U.S. supporting same-sex
>   marriage.[29] This resolution (and the sanctification of same-sex
>   marriages), however, is not supported by some congregations.[29] Of
>   particular note, the Iglesia Evangelica Unida de Puerto Rico, a
>   long-standing conference within the UCC, voted by a 3–1 margin to
>   withdraw its affiliation with the UCC over the same-sex marriage
>   issue.[30] And the Biblical Witness Fellowship, a conservative
>   evangelical organization that is a small but vocal voice within the
>   denomination, accepts only heterosexual marriage.[31]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Church_of_Christ#Same-sex_marriage